# Are there any drawbacks to running Perforce server in case-insensitive mode on Linux?

Tags: server, version-control, migration, database-migration, perforce

In the process migrating a Perforce server from a Windows server to a Linux one, the [migration guide](https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2538) lists a lot of meticulous steps for converting the depot's case sensitivity, [using the `p4migrate` tool](https://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/p4-migrate/p4migrate.html) to edit a checkpoint file that the databases will be restored from, and batch renaming the versioned `*.v` and other files.

However, a Perforce server (`p4d`) on Unix can simply be run in case-insensitive mode, using the  `-C1` parameter. With that, a lot of steps are skipped: generating conflict maps, translation maps, editing checkpoints, renaming files, etc., which makes the migration process considerably less error-prone / time-intensive.

Therefore, the question of "why even bother switching the sensitivity" is evident. Are there any obvious upsides?

In my case, a case-insensitive server has been functioning on a Windows server for a years, and fulfilled all needed tasks for the clients that were connecting to it. Would running a server with the same databases, in the same case-insensitive way, but on Linux from now on, be in any way different from the client side? The server admin side doesn't concern me so much: in my experience, once set up, the server just keeps running with little maintenance needed.

Comment: The primary drawback, in my experience, is that there are many people who run their servers in case-insensitive mode, but they have case-sensitive tools (or they themselves have case-sensitive sensibilities) so they get perturbed by the inevitable case inconsistencies in a case-insensitive server.  Make sure you really *want* case insensitivity and that everything which is interacting with Perforce is itself case-insensitive.

Comment: Anecdotally -- I do most of my development on a case-insensitive client platform (Windows) against a case-sensitive Perforce server, and I've never had a problem.  It seems to generally be easier for a case-insensitive client to work with a case-sensitive server than the reverse.

Comment: Thank you, @Samwise! In our team most clients are on Windows, so we chose initially a Windows-Windows client-server setup to avoid issues, but with time the upsides of having all the versioning+CI/CD infrastructure on the same Linux server have become apparent. Since most clients will keep using Windows for getting/submitting, I hope the case insensitive Linux setup will be fine. If you want to post your comments as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only potential drawback is that if you have any case-sensitive clients or tools, you're likely to eventually wish that you were running the server in case-sensitive mode, since case-insensitive servers tend to breed case inconsistencies (e.g. it's possible for different files in the same directory to have different ideas about the case of the directory name, which is fine on a case-insensitive client but may cause a case-sensitive client to split them into multiple directories).

If you've been running happily on a case-insensitive server already, there's no relative drawback in moving from Windows to Linux, and in fact keeping the same case sensitivity will make the migration easier.